# .save() multiple document mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

im using mongodb and i want to save the change of multiple document at once. for example its my code..

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
 name : String,
 age : Number,
 online : true
})
```

then for example i want to change the name of two users at once.. i use this method to get users

```
const myUsers = Users.find({
    '_id': { $in: [
        mongoose.Types.ObjectId('4ed3ede8844f0f351100000c'),
        mongoose.Types.ObjectId('4ed3f117a844e0471100000d'), 
    ]}
}
```

and its OK i get what i want, then i change names but after that when i want to save changes `myUsers.save()` gives me error, `myUsers.save() is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in a wrong way. The best an efficient way to update a document is using the `update` method, like this:

```js
var update = await model.update(...)
```

There are multiple options: `update()`, `updateOne()` or `updateMany()`...

If you only want to update one document you can use `findByIdAndUpdate()` if you know the document `_id` or `updateOne()`.

The query to update could be something like this [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CgFlD-Xyarz). Note that using `mongoose` is not necessary `{multi: true}` if you use `updateMany()`.

Into JS is exactly the same:

```js
var update = await model.update({
  "_id": {"$in": yourArrayID}
},
{
  "$set": {"name": yourNewName}
});
```

Comment: but after that, i should't use any save() or anything else?

Comment: `save()` is to insert a document into collection. If your document is already inserted, you have to use `update` because you are modifying a document, not saving a new one. Using `update` the document is automatically updated and saved in the DB.

Comment: soo i'm really thank you bro, you gave me a great note, and it help me to organize my codes too well, i'm really appreciate..